# React router redirects automatically

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a react app
When I run `yarn start` It runs the app and redirects to `http://localhost:300/ngo` and I havent given any redirect or such route in the whole code

This is my App.js router

```
   <Router>
     <div className="app">
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/" exact>
           <Home />
         </Route>
         <Route path="/login" exact>
           <Login />
         </Route>
         <Route path="/admin" exact>
           <Admin />
         </Route>
         <Route path="/profile" exact>
           <MyProfile />
         </Route>
       </Switch>
     </div>
   </Router>
 );
```

[image: Redirected URL]

[image: Not used the route]

What all are the possible errors or Fix ?

Comment: I think your default route is set as /ngo in your .firebaserc
Can you share the .firebaserc and firebase.js as well ?

Comment: Firebase.json ```{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: .firebaserc
```{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I got the error
It was that in the `package.json` the homepage was given as `https://<url>/ngo` because of which this was happening